# $P(\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{\tau_n=T\})=1$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Hey I have $\tau_n=\sigma_n\wedge\delta_n$ where $\sigma_n=\inf\{t\in[0,T] : \int_0^t|b(s)|^2ds\ge n\}$ and $\delta_n=\inf\{t\in[0,T] : \int_0^tb(s)dW(s)\ge n\}$, $b(s)\in P^2_{[0,T]}=\{f:\Omega\times [0,T]\to \mathbb{R}: f- adapted, P(\int_0^T|f(t)|^j<+\infty)=1\}$ and I have to show that

$P(\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{\tau_n=T\})=1$

Can anyone prove it?

Comment: I guess it would help if you told people what exactly you are talking about. As it is, I'm afraid the answer is not "42", but "no, thanks".

Comment: I edit a little bit my topic, all information what I have are given and I have to show that $P(\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \{\tau_n=T\})=1$